# stop java Timers in a loop to execute simultaneously

Tags: arrays, loops, timer

Need help  a bit, please. How to make it work in the following order: check value of an i, run Timer for it, ONLY when that timer is finished, do i++? For now two timers run at the same time. Tried to declare boolean isRunning, but did not help.

```
for(int i=0;i<pcArray.length;i++){            
            if(pcArray[i]==1){
               blinkGreen.start();            }
            else if(pcArray[i]==2){
                blinkRed.start();               
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't use a loop, but make the TimerTask itself enqueue the following task. Or just do a sleep in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First add a boolean variable in blinkGreen and also in blinkRed Timer like this,

In BlinkGreen:

```
boolean isRunningGreen = false;
  Timer blinkGreen = new Timer();      
  TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        // do stuff
        isRunningGreen = true;//This statement must be placed at the end/bottom of this method 
     }
  };
```

In BlinkRed:

```
  boolean isRunningRed = false;
  Timer blinkRed = new Timer();      
  TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        // do stuff
        isRunningRed = true;//This statement must be placed at the end/bottom of this method 
     }
  };
```

Now try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<pcArray.length;i++){            
            if(pcArray[i]==1){
               blinkGreen.start();  
               while(!isRunningGreen){}//waiting until the task is completed
            } else if(pcArray[i]==2){
               blinkRed.start();
               while(!isRunningRed){}//waiting until the task is completed               
            }
}
```